# Protractor doesn't pause to debug

Tags: angularjs, node.js, debugging, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to debug `Protractor-E2E-Tests` but my test doesn't pause on `browser.debugger()`. My attempt to achieve this is to

1. start my selenium server by running 'webdriver-manager start'
2. insert `browser.debugger()` to my test's code
3. run `grunt serve` to start my application
4. run `protractor debug protractor.conf.js`

my console output for **step 3** is the following:

```
Starting background Express server
debugger listening on port 5858
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
```

my console ouput for **step 4** is the following:

```
$ protractor debug protractor.conf.js
Starting debugger agent.
debugger listening on port 5858
Starting selenium standalone server...
connecting... ok
debug> Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.1.101:57265/wd/hub
.........

Finished in 10.737 seconds
```

So it runs the test without pausing as intended...

Here's my protractor.conf.js:

```
'use strict';

exports.config = {

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || '9000'),

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  specs: [
    'e2e/**/*.spec.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

**edit**

and here's my test's code:

```
it('should help to debug', function(done) {
        console.log('before debugger'); //gets displayed in console
        browser.debugger();
        console.log('after debugger'); //gets displayed in console as well, but shouldn't
        done();
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the `browser.debugger()` line is actually executed?

Comment: yes I'm sure because of logging (updated my post with my test's code and console output for step 3)

as you can see now, step 3 lets the debugger listen to the same port, as executing step 4 does...

Comment: is your port 5858 already in use, this could cause debugger to misbehave sometimes.

Comment: `browser.explore()` works happily in my OS X laptop but fails on Windows 7. I still haven't understood why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on windows, I have Angular universal. 
When I had both `debugger()` and `pause()` worked for me. It paused and I could navigate in cmd:

```
browser.pause();
browser.debugger();
```

Answer (score -3):

use **browser.pause();**
--see details at http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.pause